# Can not set input range value to zero by hand

Tags: html

I try to create slide bar than have value between -90 to 90 with step of 1.

```
 <input  min="-90" max="90" value = 0 step="1" class="vertRange"  type="range">
```

This is how I made it. When I test on browser, Its value displayed as zero, But when I move it, the value just bouncing around -1 and 1. I can not set the value to zero ever again.
Is that kinf of bug or it is some logic behind that?
Anyway, when I change code to

```
<input  min="-91" max="90" value = 0 step="1" class="vertRange"  type="range">
```

Now I can stop at zero but I don't want lower value to be -91.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just realize what suspicious in my code here.

```
  .vertRange {
    writing-mode: bt-lr; /* IE */
    -webkit-appearance: slider-vertical; /* WebKit */
    width: 8px;
    height: 179px;
    padding: 0 5px;
    margin:auto;
```

}
Seem like it got devider problem with 179 pixels height.
So I just change height value to 180 and it work normally fine.